# Using Scala objects in Apache Spark programs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

we're having some unexpected behaviour from a program written in Scala that uses Apache Spark. In particular, we are defining a Scala `object` like the following:

```
object MyObject {
  // A constant that will be used in a transformation
  private val SomeConstant = "Some usefull constant"

  // ... some code

  def transform(rdd: RDD[SomeObject]) = {
    val transformed = rdd.map {r => 
      Try {
        // some code that can throw an exception
      }
    }.map {
      case Success(s) => // return some string
      case Failure(e) => SomeConstant
    }
    transformed 
  }
}
```

Now, it happens that in case of a `Failure`, the constant `SomeConstant` is not yet initialized when the `transform` function is executed (invocation of the function is done outside the `object`). So, the `map` transformation for that object return the `null` value.

**UPDATE**
If we change the declaration of the `private` constant to

```
private lazy val SomeConstant = "Some usefull constant"
```

everything goes well.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: "Now, it happens that in case of a Failure, the constant SomeConstant is not yet initialized when the transform function is executed (invocation of the function is done outside the object)."

This shouldn't happen, the object's constructor is run when the object first accessed, including calling any of its methods.

Comment: I know, and that's why I can't figure out what it's going on here.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. Code is oversimplified and you are running into standard initialization order problems because `SomeConstant` is used somewhere in the constructor; 2. The object is getting serialized/deserialized (maybe you assign it to a local variable or a field?) and something goes wrong there.

Comment: I agree with zero323: an actual reproducible example would be useful.